# How to use font-weight with Google Fonts

Tags: google-webfonts

I'm doing a mockup of a wireframe. I was told they want to use this font: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato?selection.family=Lato

BUT they want the light* version. I can't seem to figure out how to use the light version of this font.

I have the Google link in my header. Then I have the style:

```
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
```

But how do I access the lighter version of the font in the documentation?

Comment: You need to import the font with its weights. Go thru the Google web font site to get the code with all the weights you need.

Comment: Thank you sir! Could not figure out how to do that. It's in another tab of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS found on Google's font page:

```
element.style {
  font-family: "Lato script=all rev=1", "Adobe Blank";
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}
```